# React TypeScript: Convert text from input to number

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I want to perform some basic arithmetic on the two input fields, but typescript and my linter are fighting against me...

```
const Tokens: React.FC = () => {
  const buy = useRef<HTMLInputElement>(null);
  const price = useRef<HTMLInputElement>(null);

  const calcQuantity = (event: React.ChangeEvent) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (buy.current && price.current) {
      const perchasingQty = buy.current.value * price.current.value
      console.log(perchasingQty);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
        <input type='number' name='buy' defaultValue='10000' ref={buy} onChange={calcQuantity}/>
        <input type='number' name='price' ref={price} readOnly defaultValue='4.6'/>
    </div>

  )
```

The error I get is

```
The left-hand side of an arithmetic operation must be of type 'any', 'number', 'bigint' or an enum type.ts(2362)
```

And if I convert them to a number with parseInt I get the linter firing off

```
Calls to 'parseInt' are not allowed. tsstyle#type-coercion (ban)tslint(1)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To convert in typescript, you can use the Explicit casting using `Number(buy.current.value)`

Or you can use an implicit conversion :

```
 const buyCurrentValue = +buy.current.value
 const priceCurrentValue = +price.current.value
 const perchasingQty =  buyCurrentValue * priceCurrentValue
 console.log(perchasingQty);
```